# CSS responsive circles

Tags: html, css, svg, layout

How can I align center an icon and text (below icon), so that they stay at the same position inside a rectangular div when it's getting resized? Here is the example of what I meant. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNB9u.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card{
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid skyblue;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <span class="circle"></span>
</div>
```

Try to use `display: flex`